# How to monitor memcache statistics on amazon

Tags: amazon-ec2, memcached

I have configured memcache in the Amazon instance. I need to monitor the memcache running statistics as well the queries executed in the memcache. Please provide suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you have deployed Memcached by using the [Amazon ElastiCache service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/WhatIs.html), then numerous metrics are available in Amazon CloudWatch.

See: [Metrics for Memcached](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/CacheMetrics.Memcached.html)

If you have created your own Memcached deployment, you will have to create your own method for monitoring metrics.